# Python: problems editing size fonts in plot

Tags: python, fonts

I don't know what I did, but suddenly font size of all my plots have changed I don't know what caused it

```
    ax = plt.gca()
PRC_T3.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.8)
PRC_RF6.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.8)
PRC_LR9.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Curva Precision VS Recall para Dados Balanceados SMOTE')
```

[image]

this is just one examples, but all graphics are following the same effect

I would appreciate a lot of help

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size back to what you using rcparams:

`plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})`

Just replace '22' with whatever size you want.

The list of all parameters you can tweak is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html). Scroll to the section called 'Default values and styling'.